# PHP sql: select a chunks of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select chunks of 5 rows every time I make a database call.

In my DB, some columns might have been deleted and others not, so the ID column can have "gaps", like missing numbers, something like this:

```
ID   name     category   ....

33   xxxx     xxxxxxx

34   xxxx     xxxxxxx

38   xxxx     xxxxxxx

40   xxxx     xxxxxxx

41   xxxx     xxxxxxx

45   xxxx     xxxxxxx

49   xxxx     xxxxxxx

...
```

I have ben trying with something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Products LIMIT 33, 5";
```

I understood that adding `LIMIT`to the query it will take the next following 5 rows starting by 33, however it does not seem to be working.

Any better suggestion to get 5 rows starting by a specific ID each time??

Comment: `where id_field_name > $id` might be the droid you're looking for

Comment: hey @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, that will take any ID bigger than the specified in $id, that is ok, but how do i limit it to 5 results on each call

Comment: using limit offset is not connected with id. It is working with rows.  use condition like ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs proposed. Also store the last selected id and change the condition on each call. Use Limit to limit rows to 5

Comment: @eddie sorry for late reply but looks like it all worked out - u_mulder's answer is what I mean by using the where :)

Comment: no worries mate!, all in order now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read manual for limit clause, you will see definintion:

```
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count ...
```

So in your case `LIMIT 33, 5` means `SKIP 33 records and TAKE 5 following records`, and **not** `FIND RECORD WITH ID = 33 and TAKE 5 following records`.

So, your option is to use a where-clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID > 33 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The values that follow the `LIMIT` keyword are the offset and the number of rows from the complete recordset to return. They are not IDs or other values returned by the query.

Read about MySQL [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

If you want to get 5 rows starting with the one having ID `33` then your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ID >= 33
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 5
```

Without `LIMIT 5`, the query above returns all the rows having `ID` greater than or equal with `33`, sorted in ascending order by their `ID`. The `LIMIT 5` clause (which is a short for `LIMIT 0, 5`) tells MySQL to return only the first `5` rows from the list.